# TinyOS Simulator: make micaz sim, missing Platform File (TOSSIM)

Tags: python, tinyos

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I recently installed tinyOS like shown in the official wiki:
[Here](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Automatic_installation)

Then I had some issues with TOSSIM and python support, so I followed this guide to troubleshoot:
[Here](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/TOSSIM#Appendix_A%3a_Troubleshooting_TOSSIM_compilation)

Anyway, I'm still getting a strange error when trying to compile `$ make micaz sim` , passing the parameter sim.

Here is the output I get whenever I try to compile:

```
 mkdir -p simbuild/micaz
 placing object files in simbuild/micaz
 writing XML schema to app.xml
 compiling BlinkAppC to object file sim.o

ncc -c -shared -fPIC -o simbuild/micaz/sim.o -g -O0 -tossim
    -fnesc-nido-tosnodes=1000 -fnesc-simulate
    -fnesc-nido-motenumber=sim_node\(\) -fnesc-gcc=gcc -Wall
    -Wshadow -Wnesc-all -target=micaz
    -fnesc-cfile=simbuild/micaz/app.c -board=micasb
    -DDEFINED_TOS_AM_GROUP=0x22 --param max-inline-insns-single=100000
    -DIDENT_APPNAME=\"BlinkAppC\" -DIDENT_USERNAME=\"samu\"
    -DIDENT_HOSTNAME=\"samu-VirtualBox\" -DIDENT_USERHASH=0x797762e4L
    -DIDENT_TIMESTAMP=0x5352a819L -DIDENT_UIDHASH=0x1e3b19c4L
    -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Wno-nesc-data-race BlinkAppC.nc
    -fnesc-dump=components -fnesc-dump=variables
    -fnesc-dump=constants -fnesc-dump=typedefs -fnesc-dump=interfacedefs
    -fnesc-dump=tags -fnesc-dumpfile=app.xml
**Missing platform file for target micaz
For the TinyOS directory /home/samu/Scrivania/TinyOS/tinyos-main/tos**
the following targets have valid platform files:
 btnode3 epic eyesIFXv1 eyesIFXv2 intelmote2 iris mica2 mica2dot micaz mulle null sam3s_ek sam3u_ek shimmer shimmer2 shimmer2r span telosa telosb tinynode ucmini z1
**make: **[sim-exe] Error 2**
```

I hope that somebody could help me. I'm really not able to find out why I get this error, since the platform files *are* in the specified directory. 
Thank you in advice.

Comment: Problem solved. 

The error pops out NOT because of python, but because of TinyOS' .platform files which are hidden. 

Pulling this git repository solved the problem:
https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/pull/182